# How to handle shouldInterceptRequest parameter change in API21?

Tags: android, android-webview

In API21 Google modified shouldInterceptRequest method to use `WebResourceRequest request` instead of `String url`. 
Is there any way I could write a generic class extending `WebViewClient` and handle both methods? 
My minimum API version is 18.

Thanks
Krystian

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Google modified shouldInterceptRequest method to use WebResourceRequest request instead of String url

No, they added a *second* `shouldInterceptRequest()` method. Both are available in API Level 21+; the `String` variant is available on API Level 11+. While the `String` one is marked as deprecated, the `String` variant should be supported for quite some time, for backwards compatibility.

> Is there any way I could write a generic class extending WebViewClient and handle both methods?

The built-in implementation of the `WebResourceRequest` version of `shouldInterceptRequest()` simply calls the `String` implementation of `shouldInterceptRequest()`:

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
        WebResourceRequest request) {
    return shouldInterceptRequest(view, request.getUrl().toString());
}
```

(from [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewClient.java) as of right now)

So, you have two choices:

1. Just override the `String` edition, if you do not need the `WebResourceRequest`, and it will be used on all relevant API levels.
2. Override both, knowing that the `WebResourceRequest` one will be used on API Level 21+ and the `String` edition will be used on API Levels 11-20.

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare, in fact what I did was implementing both methods and using `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)` on the one from API21.

Comment: I think overriding string version should be just fine.